# Is it an acceptable answer, if it advices to change the implementation?

Tags: discussion, specific-answer

So there is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40009804/4273199) about GMod Lua. The OP basically wants to store a number in a table and this number will be "linked" to a specific `Player`. The OP asks for help with writing into the table.

I thought it would be better to implement the functionality in a different way. In a way that should be more intuitive in usage and lightweight in code and CPU load and also be more OOP. So I wrote [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44908016/4273199).

But while my answer should be helpful for the OP since it will do what the OP wants, I'm unsure if it's an acceptable answer. My answer got completely rid of the code in question.

Comment: In my opinion, your not FORCED to re-use any of the code provided by the OP to make your answer. What if he is wrong from the very beginning ? Or simply if you can program the same behavior with lighter, more readable code ? If you understand what the OP wants, then there is no predefined way to solve his problem. If you solve it better with your own code... go for it.

Comment: It's not really about reusing or not reusing code from op. It's more about solving a problem with X, with simply dropping X and using Y instead

Comment: Yeah.. sounds like you found an XY problem and fixed it :P.  For context, an XY problem is "How do I do Z using X? I've been trying and X doesn't work because [whatever]" and then the answer is "Y is actually easier and faster to get to Z. Use that"

Comment: Good to know. So I can happily continue to answer this way. Maybe extend your `XY Problem` comment to a short answer?

Comment: Absolutely, like if someone come and ask you to fix his 30 years old computer, you will probably tell him he is better to buy a new one... you get the point.

Comment: See also: [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)